# How do you find which key in a dictionary has the longest list of values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am attempting to figure out which Key in my dictionary has the longest list of values. I am in a very simple Computer Science class so I cannot use lambda and other complex terms. I'm wondering if there is a way to use loops, if statements, and len to do so?

Also how would I display the value of the key with the longest list of values?

Comment: Yes - [loops, if statements](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html) and ```len``` is the way to go.  Make sure you take a look at all the [```dict``` methods](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) one of them will help also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution can go like this:

```
max_len = 0
max_key = ""
for key in d:
    cur_len = len(d[key])
    if cur_len>max_len:
        max_key = key
        max_len = cur_len
print max_key
```

Comment: Thank you! what exactly would I print in this situation is I wanted to print the name of the key with the longest list as its value?

Comment: @user4307103: See the edit. This prints the key whose value is the list of maximum length. Kindly accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Oddly enough this is generating different results every time I run it, but this is extremely close to what I need.

Comment: @user4307103: Different results? Can you explain?

Comment: Don't you need to set the value of max_len when you find a longer list?

Comment: @PaulRooney: Oops!! Ya did now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
x={'a':[9,8],'b':[1,2,3],'c':'1,2,3,4'}
print [k for k in x.keys() if x[k]==max(x.values(),key=len)]
```

You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

preds = {'lion': ['gazelle', 'zebra', 'antelope'], 'eagle': ['sparrow', 'mouse'], 'crocodile': ['gazelle', 'antelope', 'buffalo', 'zebra']}

byprey = sorted([(len(v), k) for k, v in preds.iteritems()], reverse=True)

num, predator = byprey[0]
print predator
```

For python 3 you need only change `iteritems` to `items` e.g.

```
byprey = sorted([(len(v), k) for k, v in preds.items()], reverse=True)
```

and print is a function

```
print (predator)
```